# Simple Injector: The supplied type QaCommandHandler contains unresolvable type arguments

Tags: c#, generics, simple-injector

I hope I have the terminology correct, but here's my scenario:

I have a set of concrete classes implementing an interface: `ICommandHandler<TCommand>`.

The `ICommandHandler<TCommand>` interface has a type parameter that relates to the command being handled, and looks like this:

```
public interface ICommandHandler<in TCommand>
    where TCommand : ICommand
{
    void Handle(TCommand command);
}
```

Pretty straight forward, but I have a decorator that wraps some of these command handlers:

```
public class QaDecorator<TCommand> : ICommandHandler<TCommand>
    where TCommand : IQaCommand
{
    private readonly ICommandHandler<TCommand> _handler;
    private readonly ICommandHandler<CreateQaItemCommand<TCommand>> _createQaHandler;
    private readonly ICommandHandler<UpdateQaDataCommand<TCommand>> _updateQaHandler;

    public QaDecorator(
        ICommandHandler<TCommand> handler,
        ICommandHandler<CreateQaItemCommand<TCommand>> createQaHandler,
        ICommandHandler<UpdateQaDataCommand<TCommand>> updateQaHandler)
    {
        _handler = handler;
        _createQaHandler = createQaHandler;
        _updateQaHandler = updateQaHandler;
    }

    public void Handle(TCommand command)
    {
        // If conditionA is met
        if (conditionA == true)
        {
            _updateQaHandler.Handle(updateQaData);
            return;
        }

        // If conditionB is met
        if (conditionB == true)
        {
            _createQaHandler.Handle(createQaItem);
            return;
        }

        // Otherwise...
        _handler.Handle(command);
    }
}
```

As you can see, the desire here is to have a decorator that can redirect a command - under certain conditions - to a different command that performs some actions generically, meaning it doesn't matter what the original command was.

Sorry for the long introduction, but here's where things are falling over. I'm trying to wire up Simple Injector with the correct configuration to handle this and I have the following:

```
container.Register(typeof(ICommandHandler<>), new[] {typeof(ICommandHandler<>).Assembly}, Lifestyle.Scoped);
container.Register(typeof(ICommandHandler<>), typeof(QaCommandHandler<>), Lifestyle.Scoped);
container.RegisterDecorator(
    typeof(ICommandHandler<>),
    typeof(QaDecorator<>),
    Lifestyle.Scoped);
```

Bearing in mind that `QaCommandHandler<>` implements the following interfaces:

```
public class QaCommandHandler<TEntity> : ICommandHandler<UpdateQaDataCommand<IQaCommand>>, ICommandHandler<CreateQaItemCommand<IQaCommand>>
```

The error that I get is:

> The supplied type QaCommandHandler contains unresolvable type arguments. The type would never be resolved and is therefore not suited to be used.

So I have the following questions:

1. What is the type argument that it cannot resolve?
2. How can I modify my registrations so that it can resolve the dependencies?

Answer (score 1):

> What is the type argument that it cannot resolve?

There's only one type argument in `QaCommandHandler`, namely `TEntity`. That is the unresolvable type argument. Since the implemented interfaces don't use this type argument, it could be anything and Simple Injector can't guess which type to fill in for you.

> How can I modify my registrations so that it can resolve the dependencies?

I have no idea. Nowhere in your commands you seem to specify the entity.